# how to install the module for mysql?

Tags: python, linux, django, linux-mint

please help solve the problem. I need to use mysql for django.

I installed the module with the command:

```
apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

Next, I'm trying to create a table:

```
python ./manage.py syncdb
```

The result is the following error message:

```
  File "/home/kalinin/.virtualenvs/mailsender_project/mailsender_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 17, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

just tried:

```
pip install MySQL-python
easy_install MySQL-python
```

more:

```
    (mailsender_env)kalinin@kalinin ~/.virtualenvs/mailsender_project/mailsender $ pip install MySQL-python
    Downloading/unpacking MySQL-python
      Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108kB): 108kB downloaded
      Running setup.py (path:/home/kalinin/.virtualenvs/mailsender_project/mailsender_env/build/MySQL-python/setup.py) egg_info for package MySQL-python
        sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
          File "/home/kalinin/.virtualenvs/mailsender_project/mailsender_env/build/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
            metadata, options = get_config()
          File "setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
            libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
          File "setup_posix.py", line 25, in mysql_config
            raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
        EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
        Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
        sh: 1: mysql_config: not found

    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

      File "/home/kalinin/.virtualenvs/mailsender_project/mailsender_env/build/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>

        metadata, options = get_config()

      File "setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config

        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")

      File "setup_posix.py", line 25, in mysql_config

        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))

    EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found

    ----------------------------------------
    Cleaning up...
    Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /home/kalinin/.virtualenvs/mailsender_project/mailsender_env/build/MySQL-python
    Storing debug log for failure in /home/kalinin/.pip/pip.log



more:
(mailsender_env)kalinin@kalinin ~/.virtualenvs/mailsender_project/mailsender $ sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
libmysqlclient-dev is already the newest version.
Следующие пакеты устанавливались автоматически и больше не требуются:
  libgsoap4 liblcms2-2:i386 libvncserver0 ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386
Для их удаления используйте «apt-get autoremove».
обновлено 0, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 438 пакетов не обновлено.
(mailsender_env)kalinin@kalinin ~/.virtualenvs/mailsender_project/mailsender $ sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
python-mysqldb is already the newest version.
Следующие пакеты устанавливались автоматически и больше не требуются:
  libgsoap4 liblcms2-2:i386 libvncserver0 ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386
Для их удаления используйте «apt-get autoremove».
обновлено 0, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 438 пакетов не обновлено.
(mailsender_env)kalinin@kalinin ~/.virtualenvs/mailsender_project/mailsender $ python manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/kalinin/.virtualenvs/mailsender_project/mailsender_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/kalinin/.virtualenvs/mailsender_project/mailsender_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/kalinin/.virtualenvs/mailsender_project/mailsender_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/kalinin/.virtualenvs/mailsender_project/mailsender_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "/home/kalinin/.virtualenvs/mailsender_project/mailsender_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 130, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "/home/kalinin/.virtualenvs/mailsender_project/mailsender_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 188, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "/home/kalinin/.virtualenvs/mailsender_project/mailsender_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 177, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/home/kalinin/.virtualenvs/mailsender_project/mailsender_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "/home/kalinin/.virtualenvs/mailsender_project/mailsender_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/kalinin/.virtualenvs/mailsender_project/mailsender_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite, site
  File "/home/kalinin/.virtualenvs/mailsender_project/mailsender_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.forms import AdminAuthenticationForm
  File "/home/kalinin/.virtualenvs/mailsender_project/mailsender_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/forms.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
  File "/home/kalinin/.virtualenvs/mailsender_project/mailsender_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "/home/kalinin/.virtualenvs/mailsender_project/mailsender_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 48, in <module>
    class Permission(models.Model):
  File "/home/kalinin/.virtualenvs/mailsender_project/mailsender_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 96, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
  File "/home/kalinin/.virtualenvs/mailsender_project/mailsender_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 264, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/home/kalinin/.virtualenvs/mailsender_project/mailsender_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 124, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/home/kalinin/.virtualenvs/mailsender_project/mailsender_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/home/kalinin/.virtualenvs/mailsender_project/mailsender_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 198, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/home/kalinin/.virtualenvs/mailsender_project/mailsender_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/home/kalinin/.virtualenvs/mailsender_project/mailsender_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/kalinin/.virtualenvs/mailsender_project/mailsender_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 17, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
(mailsender_env)kalinin@kalinin ~/.virtualenvs/mailsender_project/mailsender $
```

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_config` is missing on your system or the installer could not find it.

```
# activate your virtualenv
# source virtualenv/bin/activate
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Then try installing `MySQLdb` this way:

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

You need to give access to your root for installing `python-mysqldb`.

sudo

> performs the following command with super-user (root) capabilities.
>   Many actions that require modifying
>
> system files or installing applications require extra permissions to
>   go through.

Comment: I did it as root. sudo nothing changes en

Comment: I think you are using virtualenv, so did you activated your virtualenv before installing it ?

Comment: @mailsender2015 Please check i have updated my answer. You need to install libmysqlclient-dev for your missing mysql_config.

Comment: Did you activated your virtualenvironment before installing python-mysqldb ?

Comment: Did you installed libmysqlclient-dev before installing python-mysqldb ? As i mentioned above.